# How do I track what features my User's actually use?

Tags: c#, c++, architecture, tracking

This is a high level question, but I was curious to see if anyone knew of maybe a plug in or open source software that I could integrate with my software to see what users use most or not at all? Most of our software is written in c++ and C#/WPF forms.

Comment: Keep log files and send them frequently to your company servers for analysis?

Comment: Is this how most software companies do it?

Comment: Probably yes, but you should assure your users agreed to join the survey.